# uisng a for loop to print a backwards list?

Tags: python-3.x

Below is my code I have printing this in ascending order I now need to print it in descending order but don't know how? I have tried the below code however it is not printing my desired results i.e Jill,8,1,0 first and soon

```
    sorted_list = ["jack",4,3,1,"jill",8,1,0,"bob",0,0,10,"tim",5,3,1,"sod",3,1,0]
    des_list = []
    for i in range(len(sorted_list),2,-3,-1):
        des_list.append(sorted_list[i-2])
        des_list.append(sorted_list[i - 1])
        des_list.append(sorted_list[i])
        des_list.append(sorted_list[i+1])
    print(des_list)
```

Comment: What is going on there?

Comment: I am creating a list and trying to append the different attributes to try and make it print in descending order

Comment: i am trying however my ouput is messed up

Comment: In what sense is this list "sorted"?

Comment: its just a variable name

Comment: okay, but how are you going to print it reversed if it is not sorted in the first place?

Comment: i need it in descending order

Comment: i just need to print it in descending order it doesn't necaessarily have to be sorted

Comment: Oh, you mean the numbers that follow the names need to be in descending order?

Comment: yes that's it finally

Comment: Is it not already in that order? 4,3,1 - 8,1,0 - 0,0,10 * nevermind that one isn't

Comment: No I need it to print

Comment: jill,8,1,0,tim,5,3,1,jack,4,3,1

Comment: because the numbers belong to that name

Answer (score 3):

OP is incredibly vague and I can't determine any way in which the list provided is 'sorted' while a reversal of the list would print out 'jill' first. At any rate, I've assumed:

- The strings are supposed to be names
- The ints that follow are attributes of the aforementioned names

With that, I created a dict that holds the names and attributes. This would be sorting by alphabetical name with the attributes in their original order.

```
sorted_list = ["jack",4,3,1,"jill",8,1,0,"bob",0,0,10,"tim",5,3,1,"sod",3,1,0]

nameDict = {}
tmp = None
for _ in sorted_list:
    if isinstance(_, str):
        tmp = _
        nameDict[tmp] = []
    else:
        if tmp: nameDict[tmp].append(_)

final = []
for name in list(reversed(sorted(nameDict))):
    final += [name] + nameDict[name]

print final
```

While writing this, OP seems to have responded to my comment and apparently would like the attributes themselves in descending order.

```
sorted_list = ["jack",4,3,1,"jill",8,1,0,"bob",0,0,10,"tim",5,3,1,"sod",3,1,0]

nameDict = {} # empty dictionary {key1 : value1, key2 : value2 } etc...
tmp = None # temporary variable used to keep track of the name 
for _ in sorted_list:
    if isinstance(_, str): # if the name is a string...
        tmp = _ # ... set the temporary variable to the name
        nameDict[tmp] = [] # create an entry in the dictionary where the value is an empty list. Example: { "jill" : [] }
    else:
        if tmp: nameDict[tmp].append(_) # as long as tmp is not None, append the value to it. For example, after we hit "jill", it will append 8 then 1 then 0.

final = [] # empty list to print out
for name in nameDict: # loop through the keys in nameDict
    final += [name] + sorted(nameDict[name], reverse=True) # append the name to the final list as well as the sorted (descending) list in the dictionary

print final
```

If you need the names in their correct order, that might be a bit different because dicts are unsorted.

Comment: Thank You! i needed a for loop though ive got very limited python

Comment: There's  for loop in there. What do you mean by "I've got limited python"?

Comment: knowledge I know nothing about dicts

Comment: What you're asking shouldn't be done with a simple for loop. Please read up on the fundamentals of python before asking a question like this.

Comment: I purposely wrote this verbosely so it would be easy to understand. I'll comment it, but that's all I'm willing to do.

Comment: Thank You!! is there any way you  can edit my top code

Comment: @Goodies I admire your patients and determination in this. You shouldn't tolerate this kind of vagueness and demands normally..